# Uable to get the product name from the model

Tags: python, django

I've create 3 models for the Order processing. However, I couldn't show the product name on template for every single order. Does my for loop logic or 'get' method go wrong?

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
 product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=True)
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.product_name

class OrderItem(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
 item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
 ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.product_name}"

class Order(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
 items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
 start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

view.py:

```
def user_info(request):
 orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=True).order_by('-start_date')
 context = {
    'orders': orders,
 }

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

home.html:

```
 {% for order_item in orders.items.all %}
     <p>{{ order_item.item.product_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `orders` from your view which is a queryset so you can't do `orders.items.all`. You should do a for loop to loop over orders and then get the items:

```
 {% for order_item in orders %}
     <p>product names for order id {{order_itme.id}}:</p>
     {% for item in order_item.items.all %}
         <p>{{ item.item.product_name }}</p>
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Note that this will renders all items for all orders. You should filter the result if you just need one or some of them.